# import python file from docker volume

Tags: docker, python-import, docker-volume

I have a docker volume that I created by running `volume create my_volume` and have been running my docker image with the command `docker run -v my_volume:/Volumes/docker-volume/ my_image`.  Within the `docker-volume` directory I have a python file that I would like to import, but I can't figure out how to do so.  Everything I've tried results in a ModuleNotFound error.  It feels like there's some fundamental issue, perhaps relating to how a docker image interacts with a volume, that I'm missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you want share local file, than use `-v` or copy it to container by use `cp`

Comment: There are a lot of possible errors here. Maybe it is the python path, if so add this to the docker command `-e PYTHONPATH=/Volumes/docker-volume/my_image`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with your volume mapping.

The volume mapping syntax is of format "-v {local volume}:{directory inside container}

So you would have to create that particular directory in your image before mapping it.